# Facebook like button not showing up in iframe

Tags: plugin-recommendation, facebook

I have tried what seems like every plugin to add the facebook like button to my site, but none of them are displaying on the page.

I am trying to use the iframe method to avoid having to create an app id to use the XFBML method. The iframe gets created in the right spot, but nothing is showing on the page.

Can anyone recommend a plugin that is currently working?  I'm only interested in adding a Like button, I don't need other social sharing, but at this point, I'm willing to use whatever works!

Comment: please show me the code you are adding

Comment: Here is code straight from the [developer facebook page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) `<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=200&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`  Like I mentioned, I have tried multiple other plugins and none of them are working for me either.

Comment: just posted my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most reliable results, you need to create and App at FB. Try
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/

Comment: If you're creating an app for a client's site to use, do you use their personal account to create the app or your own?

Comment: You create the APP in the account you want to access with the plugin and want to "Like", not your own. Follow the instructions that the plugin itself will give you.

Comment: You can create the application on your own account and add the other person as an administrator to it. Then, when you're done with the development for them, remove yourself as the admin. I've done this for people before.

Comment: @Otto: good point

Comment: Ah, I thought about that but I wasn't sure if that would break the app ID.  Great job!

Comment: **I'm so dumb.**  I just realized that the reason it wasn't showing up was due to _a chrome extension I have to block connections to facebook_...  ([Disconnect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jeoacafpbcihiomhlakheieifhpjdfeo))  Sorry for wasting everyone's time.  I suppose it's a lesson in troubleshooting.  Thanks @Otto for the tip on managing the app.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing something.... place this on your header

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=262517660470312";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

that's all